# Split values from hash to another hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a Hash like this. In this there are some repeated values like ID and VALUES are coming as shown in the given below code.

```
HASH = {
TEST => 'xxx',
STACK => 1,
  'ID{0}' => '111',
  'ID{1}' => '222',
  'VALUE{0}' => 'Test',
  'VALUE{1}' => 'Sample',
};
```

I want to take these values out to another Hash as given below.

```
Hash ={
0 => { ID => '111', VALUE => 'Test }
1 => { ID => '222', VALUE => 'Sample' }
}
```

How i can do this in Perl?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow is probably the wrong place for your question.

Comment: How is your first hash created? The best approach will be to create the second hash at the same time as the first.

Comment: Is this a data structure you've pasted or some text? It doesn't look like it's a hash already. But it's doable to map 'tween the two via `keys` `values` and maybe hash slices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make a hash of hashes

```
%hash = 
( 
  TEST => 'xxx',
  STACK => 1,
  1 => {
  'ID' => '111',
  'VALUE' => 'Test',
  } , 
    2 => {
      'ID' => '222',
      'VALUE' => 'Sample',
   }
);
```

to access them

```
$hash{1}->{ID};
```

here is a link for more info on hash of hashes [LINK](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: you could also use an hash of an array of hashes

Comment: I've edited this answer to remove a link to a copyright-violating copy of a really out-of-date Perl book and replaced it with a link to the official documentation. Please don't put links like that on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, np. Didn't realise there are good and bad links. I'll keep it to offical perl and perl maven. Cheers